# the sum of the invertible elements of a finite ring:$S^2=S$ or $S^2=0$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let S be the sum of the invertible elements of a finite ring. Prove that $S^2=S$ or $S^2=0$.
If $1+1 \ne 0$ then $x \ne -x$ so $S=0$. I do not know how to show it when $1+1=0$. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Is the ring commutative?

Comment: No, it is not commutative

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take the list of all $k$ invertible elements. What happens when we multiply all of them (pick a side, but make sure it's the same side every time) by some invertible element $x$?

Comment: I can not figure what will happen...

Comment: This first step is just about the group structure - multiplying all of the elements of a finite group by some particular element. Try a few examples.

Comment: The set $\{x_1,...,x_2\}$ is equal to $\{xx_1,...,xx_2\}$ because the elements are distinct.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at. Multiplying by an invertible element just permutes the list. Now, add them up: $S=xS$. And then, sum that over $x$...