# Root of unity and zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity

In a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity_modulo_n#Properties) article on roots of unity modulo n, in the section on roots of unity, it is stated:

> If $x$ is a $k$-th root of unity and $x-1$ is not a zero divisor, then $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} x^j \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, because $(x-1) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} x^j \equiv x^k -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

---

When I first read it, I accepted it, the equation makes sense and is plausible.

But, on re-reading, I found that $x-1$ is not a zero divisor to be a strong condition, if we assume that we are "only" dealing with roots of unity. Because assuming we know that $x^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ is a $k$-th root of unity, how should it follow that $x-1$ is not a zero divisor?

If, on the other hand, primitive roots were assumed, then I could accept that $(x-1)$ is not a zero divisor, because here it is true that firstly $x^k \equiv 1$ and secondly $x^j \not\equiv 1$ for $j=1,...,k-1$.

---

**In a nutshell**: I am interested (if possible) in how to deduce from $x^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ that $x-1$ is not a zero divisor.

---

I hope my question has the appropriate motivation to be discussed here. I look forward to your answers and thank you in advance!

Comment: (You got the link point to a wrong 'Properties' block.) It's not true: just take $x = 1$, or, say, $n = 2^m$ and $x = 3$. They are talking about the opposite implication. For general **finite** rings, the sum of 'roots of unity' (= invertible elements) is not necessarily $0$, but it is an [idempotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134041/the-sum-of-the-invertible-elements-of-a-finite-rings2-s-or-s2-0) of the ring.

Comment: Assuming we would have the additional information that the order of $x$ corresponds to $k$, then you could claim that $x-1$ is not a zero divisor because all other $x^j \not\equiv 1$ for $j = 1,...,k-1$, right?

Comment: If $n$ is an arbitrary integer, you can't, see the second example in my comment. ($2$ is a zero divisor $\!\!\mod 2^m$ if $m > 1$; even a nilpotent.)